# Unity default properties of UI elements

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there a way to change the default properties of UI elements (explicitly their components) in Unity?

In my case, I really dislike, that a new text UI-element always truncates the text instead of overflowing it.

I know, that there's the GUI-Skin class to set properties of all UI-elements that are given that class. I do not create most of the UI in code though, but with the scene editor, so, as far as I know, using the GUI-Skin won't work.

For now, my choice is to create prefabs that differ in just the 1-2 properties I disliked from the standard gameobjects, but I figure, there's a better way, isn't it?

Comment: Don't hesitate to make some research before asking a question ;) 
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/140092/default-values-for-components.html

Comment: Yeah! I mean how hard is it to write and attach a script.

Comment: I've read that post before though. The difference is, that I'm looking for an alternative to writing and attaching these scripts to create prefabs which can then be used.

Comment: Is there no way to actually change a default value? I'm not looking for workarounds.

Comment: it's very annoying!!  **there is no real solution**, just go ahead and change it every time.  note that, of course, in a sense you can use Prefabs to completely solve this problem - but it's not really the way to go.

Comment: Additionally, as you've probably noticed, every single default chosen by Unity is **incredibly stupid**.  It's like they sat down and said "what is the most ridiculous default we can choose in each case, to really annoy people?" It's sort of funny in a way